# jQuery Tabs: How to disallow switching to a specific tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-tabs

I am using **jQuery Tabs**.

Some Tabs require user input.

As soon as the user switches to an other tab these input values are validated.

Now here is my question:

**How can I prevent showing any other tab as long as these input values are wrong?**

```
$("#tab").bind('tabsselect', function(){

   if ( ... )
   {
       alert ( 'Please fill all required fields before proceeding' );

      /*         
            What code do I have to place here to prevent displaying this tab?
      */

    }   

})
```

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is return false from the function and it will prevent selecting the tab.  See the [example](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs#...prevent_switching_to_the_tab_on_click_depending_on_form_validation) on how to prevent tab selection on form validation failure at the jQuery site.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable your tabs with the UI tabs options. Then they are greyed out and not clickable.

```
$('.selector').tabs('option', 'disabled', [1, 2]);
```

So you just disable every other tab that is not the selected one. That would mean though, that you will have to validate the form before the user clicks the tab.